# How to make javascript button be in fixed place on different screen sizes?

Tags: responsive-design, responsive-slides

when I view my website on different screen sizes, the button and equalizer move to different points. so how to make it's position fixed on any screen size?

button html code:

```
<div id="player" class="player">
  <i id="playback" class="fa fa-play fa-3x"></i>
</div>

<audio controls loop style="display:none">
    <source src="http://streaming.radionomy.com/MSTC-CHI" type='audio/ogg'>
    <source src="http://streaming.radionomy.com/MSTC-CHI" type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
```

css code:

```
#playback {
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 40%;
width:auto;
color:white;
}

#player:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        left: 0;
        color:white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
        transform: rotate(-75deg);
}

#playback {
        position: absolute;
        color:white;
        left:29.7%;
        top:46.25%;
        text-shadow: 0 0 40px #fff;
}

.fa-stop{
        margin-left:-0.46%;
}

#player{
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#player:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0px 20px #fff;
}
```

I've tried to make the display block, margin auto, position absolute, and determine top and left position.

```
#player {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        top: 46%;
        left: 30%;
        position: absolute;
}

#music-bar {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        top: 75%;
        left: 58%;
        position: absolute;
}
```

but still not working. any idea how to fix this issue?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You put position absolute, but the top and left values are in percentages.
What exactyl do you want to achieve? Can you show an example ?

Comment: I just want to make button and equalizer be in fixed position on different screen sizes.

Comment: It is not clear to me. What does it mean fixed position on different screen sizes?
E.g. the element is always 50px from top and 50px from right ?

Comment: exactly, a responsive button

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following snippet.

```
  position:absolute;
  top: 50;
  right:0;
```

In your example you use percentages. I think what you should use is absolute numbers (in pixels for example).

The element will be placed at the top right with 50 pixels distance to the top.